# Trouble sorting a list after using regex

Tags: regex, sorting, parsing, text

The code below is parsing data from this text sample:

```
rf-Parameters-v1020
supportedBandCombination-r10: 128 items
Item 0
BandCombinationParameters-r10: 1 item
Item 0
BandParameters-r10
bandEUTRA-r10: 2
bandParametersUL-r10: 1 item
Item 0
CA-MIMO-ParametersUL-r10
ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10: a (0)
bandParametersDL-r10: 1 item
Item 0
CA-MIMO-ParametersDL-r10
ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10: a (0)
supportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10: fourLayers (1)
```

I am having trouble replacing the first 'a' from the "ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10" line with 'u' and placing it before 'm' in the final output: [2 a(0) u m]

```
import re

regex = r"bandEUTRA-r10: *(\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassUL-r10*: *(\w.*)(" \
        r"?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassDL-r10*: *(" \
        r"\w.*)\nsupportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10: *(.*) "

regex2 = r"^.*bandEUTRA-r10: *(\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassUL-r10*: *(\w.*)(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassDL-r10*: *(\w.*)\nsupportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10: *(.*)(?:\r?\n(?!bandEUTRA-r10:).*)*\r?\nbandEUTRA-r10: *(\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassDL-r10*: *(\w.*)\nsupportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10: *(.*)"

my_file = open("files.txt", "r")
content = my_file.read().replace("fourLayers", 'm').replace("twoLayers", " ")
#print(content)
#if 'BandCombinationParameters-r10: 1 item' in content:
result = ["".join(m) for m in re.findall(regex, content, re.MULTILINE)]

print(result)
```

Comment: Do you want this exact string in the output? `[2 a(0) u m]` Because now group 2 and group 3 match `a (0)`

Comment: I want to replace group 2 a(0) with  'u' and have this output [2 a(0) u m] instead of [2 a(0) a(0) m]

Comment: If you know that you have the match for the 3rd and the 4th value, perhaps using a loop might be easier, see https://ideone.com/OfgZAr Then you can also omit separate capture groups for group 3 and 4 and just match it.

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: It worked but in the case of item 1 in the original text file, there's no  "ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10" line so the output shouldn't include 'u'. Should be [2 a(0) m]. get it?

Comment: So you mean there is only 1 optional match for `ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10`?

Comment: There are multiple and I would like for the code to only include 'u' in the output if ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10 is part of the item.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an optional part where you capture group 2.

Then you can print group 3 concatenated with  `u` if there is group 2, else only print group 3.

As you are already matching the text in the regex, you don't have to do the separate replacement calls. You can use the text in the replacement itself.

```
bandEUTRA-r10: *(\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10:).*)*(?:\r?\n(ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10)?: *(\w.*))(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassDL-r10*: *\w.*\nsupportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rg3SF7/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VEORN3)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"bandEUTRA-r10: *(\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10:).*)*(?:\r?\n(ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10)?: *(\w.*))(?:\r?\n(?!ca-BandwidthClassDL-r10:).*)*\r?\nca-BandwidthClassDL-r10*: *\w.*\nsupportedMIMO-CapabilityDL-r10:"

s = "here the example data with and without ca-BandwidthClassUL-r10"

matches = re.finditer(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    result = "{0}{1} m".format(
        match.group(1),
        match.group(3) + " u" if match.group(2) else match.group(3)
    )
    print(result)
```

Output

```
2a (0) u m
2a (0) m
```